# When does type binding happen in Rust?

Tags: rust, programming-languages, computer-science

From what I know: In C language, the "type" of a variable is bound during compile time and the value of that variable is bound during run time.

For example, in `int a = 10;`, the type `int` is bound to the variable `a` during compile time and the actual value `10` is bound (or assigned) to it during run time.

But in Rust, we have `let a = 2;`. Here, when does the type (say `i32` from any of the integer types in Rust) get bound to `a`?

I am building a front-end Rust compiler and am currently writing the parser phase. At this point, what type should I assign to these variables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type binding is performed at compile time. This is necessary so that the compiler can emit the proper machine instructions (for example, an `x86_64` processor doesn't multiply two `i32`s the same way it multiplies two `i64`s).

Many dynamically-typed languages, such as Python or Lua, will carry type information along with the values (*not* the variables) and dispatch operations at runtime based on the type of each operand. On the other hand, statically-typed languages, such as C or Rust, usually discard most of the type information; it's not necessary because the machine instructions required to perform the operation were emitted directly in the executable (which makes the statically-typed program faster than the comparable dynamically-typed program).

We can demonstrate that type binding is done at compile time by having the compiler tell us about type errors (this is known as *type checking*). Here's an example:

```
fn squared(x: f64) -> f64 {
    x * x
}

fn main() {
    let a = 2i32;
    println!("{}", squared(a));
}
```

Compiling this gives the following output:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:28
  |
7 |     println!("{}", squared(a));
  |                            ^ expected f64, found i32
```

The Rust compiler can *infer* the type of many variables based on usage (similar to how `auto` works in C++). When it can't, it'll give an error. For example:

```
fn main() {
    let a;
}
```

gives this output:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |     let a;
  |         ^
  |         |
  |         cannot infer type for `_`
  |         consider giving `a` a type
```

When the compiler encounters errors, it stops and doesn't produce a runnable executable. Since we don't have an executable form of our program, there is no "run time", so the above happens at compile time.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that "compile time" is actually composed of *many* steps. Lexing, parsing, type inference, desugaring, inlining, monomorphization, optimization, machine code generation (and probably tens or hundreds of other steps) all occur during "compile time". Knowing that types are assigned at compile time is akin to saying that a drop of water is in the Indian Ocean: it's more specific than "in an ocean", but there's still a lot of space to cover.

Comment: Ok, so if I'm writing a parser for Rust, then should I put some dummy type for a variable and move ahead?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj why not have a look at how rustc itself [does it](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libsyntax/ast.rs#L1578)? You can see it has a special type `Infer` that's made just for that kind of types that are not explicit in the source. Later on, while the compiler starts to checks the types, all the `Infer` get replaced by actual types.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the suggestion. I will have a look at it.