# How can I store a type in an array?

Tags: rust

I would like to create an array containing struct types (non-instanced), all implementing a same trait. I have tried to do this:

```rust
trait TraitA {
    fn new(number: i16) -> Self;
    fn get_name() -> &'static str;
}

struct StructA {
    bar: u8
}
struct StructB {
    foo: i16
}

impl TraitA for StructA {
    fn new(number: i16) -> Self {
        StructA { bar: number as u8 }
    }
    fn get_name() -> &'static str
    { "StructA" }
}
impl TraitA for StructB {
    fn new(number: i16) -> Self {
        StructB { foo: number }
    }
    fn get_name() -> &'static str
    { "StructB" }
}

fn main() {
    let struct_array = [StructA, StructB];

    for i in 0..struct_array.len() {
        println!("{}", struct_array[i]::get_name());
        struct_array[i]::new(i);
    }
}
```

The compiler expects an actual value, not a type.

In Python, I would do as such:

```py
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.bar = number
    def get_name():
        return "ClassA"
class ClassB:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.foo = number
    def get_name():
        return "ClassB"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class_array = [ClassA, ClassB]
    for i in range(2):    
        print(class_array[i].get_name())
        class_array[i](i)
```

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Not the type, but maybe you could store a funcion that returns a boxed trait object?

Comment: @rodrigo apologies for my ignorance. How would I achieve this ?

Comment: Something like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bfbc263b5baca243f14cd50ee50e793d)?

Comment: @rodrigo that is very interesting thank you !  I forgot to specify that there are multiple "static" functions in the Trait

Comment: Question modified.

Comment: Maybe you should consider not using static functions and make a `Factory` trait or something that implements all this statics as non-static methods. Then just keep a vector of  `Box<dyn Factory>` and done.

Comment: @rodrigo I've thought about something like that but I was wondering if there was a "cleaner" way to do this.

Comment: @op325 What rodrigo suggests is very "clean". Types are not first-class objects in Rust – they only exist at compile time, and don't have any representation at runtime. If you want a runtime representation, you need to define builder types yourself. These types can be zero-sized if you don't need to store any information on the builders.

Comment: @rodrigo can you propose an answer where you would do this pls ? I've been struggling for a few hours

Comment: [How does Rust store types at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58104462/155423)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, classes are also objects and callables, and calling them you create a new object of that type.

In Rust, as SvenMarnach commented above, types are not objects; they only exist at compile time and have no representation in the running program.

To do what you want you have to create a type that imitates the Python *class type*. Some kind of factory pattern, that will naturally be a trait. I'm assuming that you want to do something with those `TraitA` objects, other than creating them, so let's add something useful and move the building stuff to another trait:

```
trait TraitA {
    fn do_something(&self);
}
trait FactoryA {
    fn new(&self, number: i16) -> Box<dyn TraitA>;
    fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str;
}
```

Note that I'm adding a `&self` argument to every function. That is necessary because we'll want to invoke dynamic dispatching later, and in Rust you cannot have dynamic dispatch without `self`. But this trait represents your Python classes, so this member functions are analogous to Python *class methods*.

Also the `new` function could return an associated type, but that will not play well with the dynamic dispatching either, so I'm returning a *type erased* `Box<dyn TraitA>`.

Now, implementing a couple of classes is quite boring:

```
struct StructA {
    bar: u8
}
struct StructB {
    foo: i16
}

impl TraitA for StructA {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("I'm an A({})", self.bar);
    }
}
impl TraitA for StructB {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("I'm a B({})", self.foo);
    }
}
```

Implementing the factories is more interesting:

```
struct BuilderA;

struct BuilderB;

impl FactoryA for BuilderA {
    fn new(&self, number: i16) -> Box<dyn TraitA> {
        Box::new(StructA { bar: number as u8 })
    }
    fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str
    { "StructA" }
}
impl FactoryA for BuilderB {
    fn new(&self, number: i16) -> Box<dyn TraitA> {
        Box::new(StructB { foo: number })
    }
    fn get_name(&self) -> &'static str
    { "StructB" }
}
```

We use *zero sized types* (ZST) for the builders, because we have nothing to store there.

The main function is also quite straightforward. I've switched your loop into a `Iterator::enumerate` just for fun:

```
fn main() {
    let struct_array: Vec<Box<dyn FactoryA>> = vec![
        Box::new(BuilderA),
        Box::new(BuilderB),
    ];

    for (i, b) in struct_array.iter().enumerate() {
        println!("{}", b.get_name());
        let a = b.new(i as i16);
        a.do_something();
    }
}
```

This works as expected and prints ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a165c1f90977410764199f0a2a8718c)):

```
StructA
I'm an A(0)
StructB
I'm a B(1)
```